# regex - match anything in a title in quotes whether it has a slash or not

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to come up with a regex to match a title.

So say my strings are defined like so:

```
var str = 'title="one"';
var str1 = 'title="one/third"';
```

I want to be able to get the stuff in the middle of the quotes in title.

For instance if I ran the regex on str, the result would be:

one

If I ran it on str1, the result would be:

one/third

At the moment I have:

```
var re1='(title)';
var re2='(=)';
var re3='(")';
var re4='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';
var re5='(")';
var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,["i"]);
var m = p.exec(str);
var n = p.exec(str1);
//Works!
console.log(m);
//Does Not Work!
consoloe.log(n);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"([^"]+)
```

Try this.Grab the captures or groups.

or

```
var re4='((?:[a-z\/]+))';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `var re4='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'` only matches lower case letters, thus `/` fails.

This regular expression captures things between quotes:

```
/"(.+)"/.exec('title="one/third"')
```

Alternatively, if your strings are in that particular pattern, your can just replace unwanted part with empty string:

```
'title="one/third"'.replace(/^title="|"$/g, '')
```